# What is the most efficient way to take a screenshot and do analysis on it on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, opencl

I need to be able to grab the output of a game and extract simple data from the HUD (get numerical data from fixed-width font UI elements, etc... simple stuff), but I need to be able to do it in real-time as the game is being played. I can analyze the images just fine, my issue is getting a screenshot fast enough.

There are multiple options that I am considering, and I need advice from those with experience on which one would be best suited to my needs.

I have considered just using Quartz Display Services or the CGWindow API to grab a screenshot and then analyze the resulting image, however this seems to be rather inefficient, and I would like to be able to do this many times per second (ideally as fast as the game is being rendered, but that may be unrealistic).

I also considered porting my image analysis stuff to OpenCL (which I may end up doing anyway due to its highly parallelizeable nature) thus eliminating the need for a screenshot to be pushed between the GPU and the CPU. If this sounds reasonable, what is the fastest way to atomically read (or maybe create a copy of) the framebuffer? There seems to be lots of documentation about sending stuff from OpenCL to OpenGL, but not the other way around, and I don't even have any control over the OpenGL portion (3rd party closed-source game).

Comment: IF it's a closed source game based on a commercial engine, there might be high-performance ways to do it from within that game's own engine, via extensions/mods/plugins.

Comment: @WarrenP Unfortunately, no. Not for this game.

Comment: Maybe this will help? QuickTime Player has a way to record the screen. Perhaps you can automate around that, even with AppleScript?  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/how-to-record-the-screen-of-an-opengl-application-without-stuttering  - Sadly it wouldn't be realtime analysis, it would be "however far behind the writing to disk of the quicktime file is".

Comment: @WarrenP Thanks, but I'm looking for a highly optimized lowish-level solution using C. I was just wondering if anyone had feedback regarding [this API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) or a more efficient solution.